# subprocess.Popen, communicate() and wget raises error when there is none?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a piece of code that I use to run commend line calls from python (probably taken from SO, but seem to have missed the source on this):

```
import subprocess
# Run cmd line
def run_cmd(cmd, verbose=True, *args, **kwargs):
    if verbose:
        print(cmd)
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True
    )
    std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
    if std_err:
        raise RuntimeError(std_err.strip())
    if verbose:
        print(std_out.strip(), std_err)
    return std_out.strip()
```

I have been using it fine, but recently I was quite confused when I realized that when called with:

```
run_cmd('wget https://zenodo.org/records/8014758/files/2DeteCT_slices1-1000.zip -P /one/of/my/folders/2detect/file.zip')
```

This would cause it to error. Took a bit to figure out because turns out that what is being printed, instead of an error, is the progress of dowloading the file and successful command, i.e. an "unrolled" version of what I get when I call the line from command line:

```
--2024-02-11 13:54:55--  https://zenodo.org/records/8014758/files/2DeteCT_slices1-1000.zip
Resolving zenodo.org (zenodo.org)... 188.184.103.159, 188.185.79.172, 188.184.98.238, ...
Connecting to zenodo.org (zenodo.org)|188.184.103.159|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 33880212893 (32G) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/one/of/my/folders/2detect/file.zip’

file.zip                           100%[===================================================================================================================>]  31.55G  20.9MB/s    in 22m 5s  

2024-02-11 14:17:02 (24.4 MB/s) - ‘/one/of/my/folders/2detect/file.zip’ saved [33880212893/33880212893]
```

I can verify the file, there is no error on it and I can unzip it well.
So, why does this piece of code basically return `std_err`? the error itself does not seem to be an error but a progress bar.

Hopefully understanding what is going on can help me fix the `run_cmd` function.

Comment: Something printing into stderr *does not mean* that actually was an error. Sometimes stderr is just for diagnostics or something that dev decided its not part of actual output and user can just filter those out if/when used in scripting..  So they put the stuff to stderr so that user can redirect those to dev/null On your code, you are now checking "was there any output to stderr and if yes, raise RuntimeError. Its a bug in your logic.

Comment: Assuming stderr is the result of an error is probably the wrong ting to do.  I would check the process exit code.  check out this:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be assuming that code written to stderr indicates a real error.  you need to check the Popen.returncode attribute after checking for the process to have finished:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! A second question about `returncode`: I can generally assume that if `0`, no error, if `-N` error, right?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, on UNIX, exit status is an 8-bit unsigned integer. It can't be negative. (It's stored as part of a 16-bit value, but the remaining bits are for describing being killed by a signal; there are macros in the C API, and functions in its Python wrapper, for inspecting those bits). Correct that 0 is the success value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, that makes sense and its in line with what I expected. Just mentoned the `-N` because of the docs linked.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, right, but `-N` is signals (information from the upper 8 bits of the 16-bit C structure), not other kinds of error; that'll represent things like a segfault or SIGTERM. _Most_ errors will be positive values (the general/"default" error value is typically 1, if a program doesn't set out a specification for which exit codes have which meanings).